# How to reset only specific fields of form in angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, angular5, angular-components

I have created a function in one of my component file that resets the form(myform):

```
`onSubmit() {
  if (this.myform.valid) {
    console.log("Form Submitted!");
    this.myform.reset();
  }
}`
```

It works perfectly fine resetting the whole form, but is it possible to just reset some of the elements and keeping other the same way.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

try this:

```
this.myform.controls['comments'].reset()
```

Comment: How can you add multiple fields to this? say `this.myform.controls['comments', 'name'].reset()`  I can't find this way of doing it in the documentation.

Comment: @Keithers try this : this.myform.reset({ comments: null, name: null})

Comment: @Abdessamad tried it but did not work, I had to replicate the code twice for the different control names `this.myform.controls['comments'].reset(), this.myform.controls['name'].reset()`

Comment: It took me way to long to find this, thanks I think this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 17):

try this one:

```
  clearForm() {
    this.myForm.get('comments').reset();
    this.myForm.get('name').reset();
  }
```

and call this function where you submit form.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

I just had this issue and although the accepted answer works, it has some tslint warnings. I ended up doing:

```
this.myForm.get('formControlName').setValue(null);
```

I'm working with Angular 8.

And if you want to do it for several fields this works too:

```
private controlNames = ['nameOne', 'nameTwo'];

this.controlNames.map((value: string) => this.myForm.get(value).setValue(null));
```

Comment: Why `map` to make side effects and ignore the results?

Comment: you are totally right, you could use forEach instead!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can access the controls using `this.myform.controls`
get the control and call `reset()` on it

Comment: one of my controls name is `comments` so i wrote `this.myform.controls.comments.reset()`. But i get error 'Unresolved variable comments'

Answer (score 2):

In your html

```
<select formControlName="idSala" (change)="clearField(1)">
 <option value="">Selecione uma sala</option>
</select>
```

`<input type="text" formControlName="titulo">`

`<input formControlName="dataHoraInicial" type="datetime-local">`

TS

```
clearField(value) {
if (value == 1) {
  this.formularioDeAgendamentoSala.controls['titulo'].reset();
  this.formularioDeAgendamentoSala.controls['dataHoraInicial'].reset();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically deletion of FormControl value:

```
private _clearFormGroupControlValue(formControlName: string) {
  this.formGroup.get(formControlName).setValue(null);
}

                          or

private _clearFormGroupControlValue(formControlName: string) {
  this.formGroup.controls[formControlName].reset();
}

                          or
private _clearFormGroupControlValue(formControlName: string) {
  this.formGroup.controls[formControlName].patchValue(null || '');
}
```