# Reset angular reactive form exclude particular field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

with reference(`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197347/how-to-reset-only-specific-fields-of-form-in-angular-5`) , I have 20 fields in form, If user click reset option I need to reset form exclude 2 fields, If am using this.form.reset() means it reset every thing, Any help appreciated

Answer (score 20):

Just look at the `onReset()` method. This code will reset everything except the `name` and `description` fields

```
formGroup: FormGroup = /* init the formGroup... */

onReset() {
    this.formGroup.reset({
        name: this.formGroup.get('email').value, 
        description: this.formGroup.get('description').value
    });
}
```

[Stackblitz repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-qk5u68)

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the controls of a `FormGroup`, and if the controls name matches the one in your exclude list, you don't reset it:

```
const exclude: string[] = ['formControlName1', 'formControlName2'];

Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
   if (exclude.findIndex(q => q === key) === -1) {
       this.form.get(key).reset();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a reset value to the reset function. Simply give the value of your two fields to it, and the rest should be empty.

```
const resetValue = {};

for (const key of this.form.value) {
  resetValue[key] = '';
}

resetValue.firstFieldToKeep = this.form.get('firstFieldToKeep').value;
resetValue.secondFieldToKeep = this.form.get('secondFieldToKeep').value;

this.form.reset(resetValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object to the reset function with Key as the formControl and value as the value you would like the control to have on reset.

```
this.form.reset({
  fomrControl1:value1,
  formControl2:value2
});
```

If you want to change the behavior of the field such as disabled or enabled, just pass in an Object instead of a value. For example:

```
this.form.reset({
  fomrControl1:{value:value1, disabled:true}, // disables this field on reset
  formControl2:value2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep those two inputs value, reset form and just patch those two again.

```
const keepValues = [
   this.form.controls.keepThis1.value,
   this.form.controls.keepThis2.value,
];
this.form.reset();
this.form.controls.keepThis1.patchValue(keepValues[0]);
this.form.controls.keepThis2.patchValue(keepValues[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey make a function reset()
and reset the `18` fields by using syntax like below.

```
 resetForm(){

    this.form.controls.formField1.reset("");
    this.form.controls.formField2.reset("");
    .
    .
    this.form.controls.formField18.reset("");
 }
```

Thank You.

Comment: weird to do it manually for every 18 fields but with my 1 field this solution is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I followed a shortcut
I did reset the full form
Then I patched the value for a control which doesn't need a reset. Refer the snippet below

```
onCancelClick(form: NgForm) {
        form.resetForm();
        Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(name => {
            if (name == "email") {
                form.controls[name].patchValue(this.emailOfmember);
            }
        });
}
```